# Return List type in JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have DTO structure like :

```
public class ADto{
  private String name;
  private String id;
  private List<BDto> bdtos;

 //Created constructor using fields
}

public class BDto{
   private String id;
   private String code;
   private List<CDto> cdtos;

 //Created constructor using fields
}

public class CDto{
  private String mKey;
  private String mVal;

 //Created constructor using fields
}
```

Used Spring MVC for fetching the data.

Below query is working perfectly fine and binding the data :

```
@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query("select new pkg.ADto(id,name) from AEntity a where a.id=?1")
public ADto getAData(Long id);
```

How can I fetch the data for the list which is in turn composed of further list using the above method?

Comment: You want to return list of `BDto` when fetching single `ADto`?

Comment: @BranislavLazic yes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return DTOs instead on enitites, you need to provide mapping between DTOs and entities. With JPQL query, the only option is to provide that mapping in constructor of the resulting object. Therefore, you need to add a constructor to ADto, which accepts BEntities, and map all nested entities to dtos in that constructor. Or in more object oriented way, the new constructor will accept AEntity as the only argument.

This is how it could look like:

getAData() method in the repository (JPQL is slightly modified by adding a.bEntities to result):

```
@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query("select new pkg.ADto(id,name, a.bEntities) from AEntity a where a.id=?1")
public ADto getAData(Long id);
```

New constructor in ADto:

```
public class ADto{
  private String name;
  private String id;
  private List<BDto> bdtos;

  public ADto(String id, String name, List<BEntity> bEntities) {
    this.id = id; this.name = name;
    this.bdtos = new ArrayList<>();
    for (BEntity b : bEntities) {
       BDto bdto = new BDto(b.id, b.code, b.cEntities); 
    /* you need to pass cEntities and map them again in the BDto 
     * constructor, or you may do the apping in ADto constructor
     * and only pass mapped values to BDto constructor */
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable eager fetch:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "adto", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<BDto> bdtos;
```

Then you can fetch it like this i.e.:

```
ADto findById(Long id); // literally!
```

Comment: Just one more thing.. adto and Bdto are no entities and just dtos..Would it be recommendable to use this way and will that work?

Comment: You will have to define new property for `BDto`: `private ADto adto;` (with getters and setters). Annotate classes properly.